# Unsure what "aquélla" refers to in this phrase

Tags: gramática, pronombres

I'm reading Arturo Perez-Reverte's *Hombres Buenos* and am a bit confused by the following:

> El siglo dieciocho fue otra de esas oportunidades perdidas: militares que leían, marinos científicos, ministros ilustrados... Estaba en marcha una renovación que poco a poco vencía la resistencia de los sectores más reaccionarios de la Iglesia y de la sociedad donde **aquélla** acechaba como una enorme araña negra.

What is aquélla pointing at here? There are a lot of candidate feminine anaphors up there and it's not clear to me which one makes the most sense. I'm curious, does one option stand out to native speakers?

Comment: Although grammatically there are several options, in the context (https://www.perezreverte.com/libro/639/hombres-buenos/) it seems obvious that renovation is not bad, and it leaves only "resistencia" and "Iglesia". Both could make sense, but "enorme araña negra" fits better the Church. Black color isn't unusual in derrogative metaphors on the Church, it has a pervasive web of agents reaching everywhere and censorship (which seems to be a topic in the book) was managed by the Church.

Answer (score 6):

The phrase has two actions `renovación` and `resistencia`, two subjects affected by `Iglesia` and `sociedad`, and a demonstrative pronoun indicating one of the actions.

Having two actions, the possibilities are to refer to the closest one, for which "esta" would be used, or to the farthest one, for which "aquella" is used.

[image]

He uses "aquella" to indicate the farthest action from the sentence without it being confused with the immediately preceding one.

In another way:

> La renovación acechaba como una enorme araña negra.

Comment: Ignoring the semantics for a moment (as tac’s answer points out, you’d hardly describe the church as ‘lurking furtively’ in Spanish society) and looking at it from a purely grammatical viewpoint, the closest option would surely be _la iglesia_. If you change _acechar_ to something like _cernerse_ to make the semantics work better, the result seems perfectly fine to me: “Los sectores más reaccionarios de la iglesia y de la ciudad sobre la que ésta se cernía como una enorme araña negra”. This would make both _renovación_ and _resistencia_ candidates for _aquélla_ (grammatically).

Comment: If you read the previous paragraph, the author begins by listing three of the main social components: military, merchants (the sailors), and politicians; the clergy and the people are mentioned in the next paragraph. This means the key element is the action that has been taking place on all of them and not one of them in particular.

Answer (score 5):

Para empezar, consideremos que podría referir a cuatro cosas distintas:

- La renovación
- La resistencia
- La Iglesia
- La sociedad

En este caso, la palabra **acechaba** proporciona la información decisiva para determinar a qué refiere el autor:

> **[acechar](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/acechar)**: Mirar, atisbar, observar con cuidado alguna cosa procurando no ser visto.

Ni la *resistencia*, ni la *sociedad* ni la *Iglesia* pueden ocultarse, al representar éstas el *statu quo* de la época. Luego, el pronombre refiere a la **renovación** que estaba siendo planificada por los revolucionarios; quienes esperaban al momento adecuado para iniciar el ataque y por lo tanto debían esperar al acecho.

**Posdata**:

Respecto a los pronombres demostrativos, las acepciones principales que se reconocen son para uso *espacial*. *Aquella (aquélla)* se usa para referir a algo que está lejos del hablante y del oyente. *Esa (ésa)* indica algo que está lejos del hablante y cerca del oyente—aunque en la práctica también se puede usar en reemplazo de *aquella*. Y *esta (ésta)* refiere a algo que está cerca del hablante.

Con un sentido similar, está el recurso de utilizar los pronombres para indicar la lejanía de los términos en el texto. Si dijimos que *aquélla* refiere a lo que está espacialmente más alejado, en general el anáforo al que está sustituyendo es el que está textualmente más lejos (el que se mencionó primero). En cambio, si por ejemplo el autor hiciera referencia a la sociedad entonces habría utilizado inequívocamente *ésta*. El uso de *ésa* con el propósito mencionado no suele verse debido a que se presta a ambigüedades—acá podría ser la resistencia o la Iglesia, pero incluso si hubieran sólo tres anáforos posibles (o menos) seguiría siendo ambigüo su uso.